# Change only one of the divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a little problem with jquery, I have this html code

```
<div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">                         
    @foreach($auctions as $auction)
    {{$auction->name}}
    <p> 
        <div id="total" class="pricenow">{{$auction->pricenow}}</div>
    <p>
    {{$auction->start_price}}
    <p>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

Then , when I use jquery I recieve all the content with the attribute document.getElementsByClassName (Thisworks correctly)

```
function convertireu(){
    var elements= document.getElementsByClassName("pricenow");
    var longitud = elements.length;
    for(var i=0;i<elements.length;i++){
        console.log(converteu(elements[i].textContent));

    }
}
```

Moreover, This return all of the results

```
function converteu(dollar)
{
    numero = /[0-9\.]$/

    if (!numero.exec(dollar))
    {
        alert("Is not a number");
    }
    {
        euro = parseFloat(0.7641);
        result= euro*parseFloat(dollar);
        console.log(result);
    }
}
```

My question is, how I can change the content in html? I tried to use append and inner and only change the last one.

Comment: What exactly you want to change?

Comment: I need to append with the correct form the console.log(resultado)

Comment: Please use english variable and function names etc when sharing your code. Programmers are lazy, and reading code in a foreign language just makes things that much harder, so you will have a harder time getting the help you need.

Comment: Ok , I change the names @codebreaker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if I correctly understand what you what, try this

```
elementos[i].innerHTML
```

[https://jsfiddle.net/okg70bqh/](http://fiddler)